# Oracle show me last login used password

Tags: oracle

I'm finding any way, how get from Oracle 11g used passwords for login.

I know DBA user and "know" normal user password. But program, that uses normal user add to his password an salt. And I need debug, what is added, because I need login to oracle with same user, but from another program, that didn't know what salt is added :(

So I can change password to user, or login, or do bad login... but I need get from oracle / logs realy used password.

Comment: Have you tried making another schema/user granted with operations on the one you need to edit instead of retrieving a password you don't know?

Comment: Users insist on that username/password must be same to all programs!

Comment: Maybe a "Proxy User" helps in this situation, see [Proxy Authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/proxya.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get user password from Oracle 11g. But if you have SYSDBA grants then you can get hash of current user password. 
So, you can do:

1. get hash of current user password and save it
   `SELECT t.password, t.spare4 FROM sys.user$ t WHERE t.name = 'SOME_USER_NAME';`
2. set new password `ALTER USER SOME_USER_NAME IDENTIFIED BY new_password`;
3. login with new password for debug;
4. and after that set the old password  `ALTER USER TEST1 IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'XXXX;YYYY'`, where XXXX is hash from `spare4` column and YYYY is hash from `password` column.